# Draw shape in map and save to server ArcGIS JavaScript version 4+

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

is it possible to use sketchViewModel to draw polygons and using applyEdits() to save as feature layer in server?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  You mention "server" but have tagged ArcGIS Online rather than ArcGIS Server so which are you coding against?

Comment: For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.